# C# : How to use Thread and know when exactly thread work is finished?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I read the UNSEEN email in my C# win form project. some times there are attached files, that the downloading make some times, so my project's UI will lock during download complete. Im using ThreadPool for getting solve this problem.

here is my code :

```
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lstEmailAddress.Count; i++)
        {
            Get(imap[i], lstEmailAddress[i].MailBox, out Emails[i]);
        }

        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lstEmailAddress.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Emails[i].Count; j++)
                {
                    Database.EmailRecieve_Insert(Emails[i][j]);
                }

                arrEmailUserControl[i].txtRecievedCount.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(arrEmailUserControl[i].txtRecievedCount.Text) + Emails[i].Count).ToString();
            }

        }));
    });
```

here is Get method that I used :

```
private bool Get(Imap4Client imap, string[,] MailBox, out List<EmailStruct> Emails)
    {
        Emails = new List<EmailStruct>();
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < MailBox.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                Mailbox inbox = imap.SelectMailbox(MailBox[i, 1]);

                int[] ids = inbox.Search("UNSEEN");

                if (ids.Length > 0)
                {
                    ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Message msg = null;

                    for (var j = 0; j < ids.Length; j++)
                    {
                        msg = inbox.Fetch.MessageObject(ids[j]);

                        EmailStruct email = new EmailStruct();
                        email.SourceAddress = msg.From.Email;
                        email.Subject = msg.Subject;
                        email.Text = msg.BodyText.Text.ToString();

                        msg.Attachments.StoreToFolder(InternalConstant.AttachmentFolder);

                        email.MailBoxID = Convert.ToInt32(MailBox[i, 0]);

                        Emails.Add(email);
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

As u can see in above code, I have an action exactly when the thread work finished. Actually, I want to inform about finishing thread work.

but the problem is here: most of the times, I got this exception when I want to fetch messages from inbox.

```
The Read method cannot be called when another read operation is pending
```

if I remove the threadpool that will work well. 
Im using threadPool just for ignoring UI lock and also knowing there the thread finished.

Is there any better way that you can suggest I?
Thanks for any helping...

Comment: Not awake enough for a full answer, but I would suggest ditching the `Thread` class and using Tasks instead. You can just create a task and use its `ContinueWith` property to specify an action that is executed when the task is done: `Task t = Task.Run(() => DoWork()).ContinueWith(() => AfterWorkDone());` (translated automatically from VB.net, hopefully correct). Or you can use `Async` and `Await` to wait in your code until a task is finished while not locking the UI either.

Comment: Sounds like you are fetching emails before the first thread has finished executing. What does the code that adding the job to the ThreadPool look like?

Comment: There's not enough information to provide an answer. Where does the exception happen? What is the complete stack trace? What causes the operation to be initiated? Why does the operation (apparently) get initiated again before the previous one had completed? There are other things that could be done to help improve the above code, but first the specific problem you are asking about needs to be addressed. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Don't just swallow exceptions. Very briefly you can do something like this: catch an exception -> do you know what you can do with it and how to fix the situation? If yes -> do/fix it. If not -> log the exception (don't forget to log exception stack trace and inner exceptions). Make sure your module is not left in half-changed state. If yes, roll back state chahges. If the exception occurred on a low level -> most likely you need to rethrow it and let high-level code decide what to do.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any better way that you can suggest?

Here is how I would do it in a modern (not anymore, if you read it in 2020) approach in my WPF application:

```
private async void DoSomethingAsync()
{
    try
    {
        DoanloadEmailsCommand.IsEnabled = false;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Do something here. For example, work with the database, download emails, etc.
            Emails = DownloadEmails();
        });
    }
    finally
    {
        DoanloadEmailsCommand.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} emails have been downloaded.", Emails.Count));
}
```

The code inside the lambda expression passed to the Task.Run() method will be executed on another thread.
Straight after creating and running the task, control flow will be returned back to the caller (in our case to the UI message loop eventually, that will continue processing other events).
When the task finishes, some "wake-up" message is sent to the application's message queue, and when the message loop receives and handles this message, the execution will continue where it has been left off.
In our case, when the task finishes, the execution will be continued on the main thread from the next line following the "await Task.Run()" call ().
So the command object will be enabled (it would be bound to a button, let's say "Download Emails", so the button will become enabled also) and the message box saying how many emails will have been downloaded will be shown.

As you can see the code is pretty clean and easy to read and understand (once you know the basics of using the async/await keywords and the Task class).

(also read my comment above on your exception handling)